# Android Service does not restart

Tags: android, service, restart

I have a service that performs an action on the timer. Service runs from activity. While the application is running, the service works fine.If I close the application using the cleanup in the launcher, the service goes restart mode, but does not restart. **is this normal?**

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service 
{
    private static Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();  
    }
    private void startService()
    {           
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 10000);
    }
    private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            //MY CODE
        }
    }    
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        startService();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```